# Azure functions host.json being ignored

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus

I'm using Azure functions to deal with my service bus queue and I wanted to add a delay for when the item in the queue is processed again when it throws an exception and puts things back into the queue.

I added this piece of code to my host.json from the Microsoft Docs

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[2.*, 3.0.0)"
  },
  "extensions": {
    "serviceBus": {
      "serviceBusOptions": {
        "retryOptions": {
          "mode": "fixed",
          "tryTimeout": "00:00:10",
          "delay": "00:00:30",
          "maxDelay": "00:01:00",
          "maxRetries": 4
        },
        "prefetchCount": 100,
        "autoCompleteMessages": true,
        "maxConcurrentCalls": 32,
        "maxConcurrentSessions": 10,
        "maxMessages": 2000,
        "sessionIdleTimeout": "00:18:00",
        "maxAutoLockRenewalDuration": "00:18:00"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However, my function is just ignoring these settings and not honoring the delay I set above.

Comment: the delay is related to the dequeue process. In your case, it will wait 30s between attempt 1 to handle the message / attempt 2, not a delay to add the message back to the queue

Comment: I may have worded it wrong in my post, my function does not wait that 30s to handle the message again

Comment: try changing the value of the mode property to title case: "Fixed"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You maybe need this offical article.

[host.json reference for Azure Functions 2.x and later](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json)

If you want to use `retry Options`, you should use below sample code.

[image]

Not use [`Properties in RetryOptions Class`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.core.retryoptions?view=azure-dotnet) .

Comment: This OP is asking for SB queue processing, the 'retry' references in this answer is (according URL provided): Controls the retry policy options for all executions in the app.
This answer is not correct in my understanding.